# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'values' (T_STRING) in E:\xampp\htdocs\study\connect.php on line 13

Tags: php

When I try to connect to my database, I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'values' (T_STRING) in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\study\connect.php on line 13

**This is my php code:**

```
<?php
    $firstName = $_POST['fname'];
    $middleName = $_POST['mname'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lname'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    //Database Connection
    $conn = new mysqli ('localhost','root','','task1');
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die('connection failed :' .$conn->connect_error);
    }else{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert to registration(firstName, middleName, lastName, password")
            values(?,?,?,?)
        $stmt ->bind_param("ssss",$firstName,$middleName, $lastName, $password);
        $stmt ->execute();
        echo "Registration Successful..";
        $stmt ->close();
        $conn ->close();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert to registration(firstName, middleName, lastName, password")
            values(?,?,?,?)
```

I think you made a mistake.
Try this instead of your code, you missed out `");`

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert to registration(firstName, middleName, lastName, password") 
            values(?,?,?,?)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing double quote issue, use it as

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert to registration(firstName, middleName, lastName, 
password)
values(?,?,?,?)");
```